# How can I instruct LESS to ignore some code?

Tags: css, less

```
body {
  color: lighten(#aaa, 10%);
  something invalid
}
```

How can I ignore "something invalid" to get it without changes in result css?

Comment: Maybe make Less compiler interpret it as a string and then output it? Would help if you can post a sample of what you mean by invalid CSS. Is it something like a old browser hack?

Comment: For example, "something invalid" might be "<?php echo $something ?>" or something like that :-)

Comment: You could do something like `-:~"1;<?php echo $something ?>"`. `-` being an invalid property in itself will make it compile but not cause anything undesired.

Comment: Thanks, but that isnt exactly what I need. I'm looking for a way to output an arbitrary string in any place of LESS file, but I'm not sure is it possible.. It would be great if ~"..." syntax worked in any place of a file.

Comment: Well, this functionality is barely to ever appear in Less (for more details see [#2172](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2172#issuecomment-54166532)). So if you need some stylesheet to be processed by Less and PHP (or any other arbitrary text replacement tool) do it in reverse, i.e. first PHP then Less.

Comment: seven-phases-max, thanks!